# TypeError: gl.texStorage2D is not a function. (In 'gl.texStorage2D(tex2d, 1, internalFormat, width, height)', 'gl.texStorage2D' is undefined)

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Log & part of code:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: gl.texStorage2D is not a function. (In 'gl.texStorage2D(tex2d, 1, internalFormat, width, height)', 'gl.texStorage2D' is undefined)
```

````
  const file = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}image-new-${imageIndex}.jpg`;

  const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(file, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  });
  tf.engine().startScope();
  const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, "base64").buffer;
  console.log("String encoded.");
  const imageData = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer);
  const tensor = decodeJpeg(imageData);
  console.log("String decoded.");
  const model = await cocossd.load();
  console.log("Model loaded.");
  const predictions = await model.detect(tensor);
  console.log("Prediction found.");```
````

Dependecies:

```
    "expo-gl": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd": "^2.2.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "4.1.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
```

Hello, I am trying to perform object detection using Tensorflow and COCO-SSD in a React Native app. It is an Expo dev build. This is the error I'm getting. Any pointers as to what might be going wrong? Both console.log("String encoded."); and console.log("String decoded."); do run so I suspect it is something to do with the COCO-SSD model and "expo-gl" and "expo-gl-cpp" packages, both of which are installed. Thank you.

EDIT I get the same error running https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/react-native/image-classification/expo on an Android emulator. It works perfectly fine on iPhone 13 Max though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator, make sure to use the maximum WebGL API level. You can choose this in the emulator's settings:

[image: emulator settings]